# How do i return 2 boolean values from a while loop? Java

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean, return

I try to return both correctPiece and correctDest but

```
return correctPiece;
```

gets underlined and the error "Unreachable code" appears.

How can I return both?

```
   while(correctPiece && !correctDest) {

            System.out.println("Click on a destination");

            toXCo = s.getToXInt();
            toYCo = s.getToYInt();

            Move found = null;

            for( Move m : moves){
                //checks if move can be done
                if (m.ToX() == toXCo && m.ToY() == toYCo){
                    //if move is allowed- exit loop
                    found = m; 
                    correctDest = true;
                }
            }

            if (found == null) {
                //if move can't be, ask for new co-ordinates
                System.out.println("This move is not legal \n");
                    correctDest = false;
                    correctPiece = false;
            }   
            return correctDest;
            return correctPiece;
        }
```

Comment: You cannot return multiple values from a function. To make sure both values are reflected back to where you called from, pass them by reference.

Answer (score 5):

By changing your `return` type to `boolean[]` and using something like

```
return new boolean[] { correctDest, correctPiece };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a Class that contains both the Booleans that you want to return, and create an object of this class and return that.

The reason this approach is better because incase you want to extend the response in future, to add a couple of more parameters, it always is easier to do that if you have an object being returned.

You code in this case would look like

```
while(correctPiece && !correctDest) {

        System.out.println("Click on a destination");

        toXCo = s.getToXInt();
        toYCo = s.getToYInt();

        Move found = null;

        for( Move m : moves){
            //checks if move can be done
            if (m.ToX() == toXCo && m.ToY() == toYCo){
                //if move is allowed- exit loop
                found = m; 
                correctDest = true;
            }
        }

        if (found == null) {
            //if move can't be, ask for new co-ordinates
            System.out.println("This move is not legal \n");
                correctDest = false;
                correctPiece = false;
        }   
        return new Response(correctDest, correctPiece);
    }
```

And you can create a Response class to capture both the values like

```
private static class Response {

    boolean correctDest;
    boolean correctPiece;
    public Response(boolean correctDest, boolean correctPiece) {
        super();
        this.correctDest = correctDest;
        this.correctPiece = correctPiece;
    }


}
```

Comment: This is the best solution.  If you demonstrated it with some code showing an example of the return value class and its use, I'd consider it the best answer.

Comment: Sure. added an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your return type to boolean[] so that you can return 2 boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

"return" terminates your method and returns the value. Everything below return is not reachable.

Try changing return type to bolean[], and change you code to something like this:

```
boolean temp[] = {correctDest, correctPrice};
return temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Return keyword exits your method, so when it first hits the return correctDest;
it will exit your method. From what I see, you can modify that code to:

```
if (m.ToX() == toXCo && m.ToY() == toYCo){ 
    return true;
}
```

and instead of return correctDest; and return correctPiece; just return false.
You don't really need to return both values.

```
if (found == null)
   return false;
```

then just go like

```
 correctDest = methodreturn();
 correctPiece = methodreturn(); // since it's true in order to enter the loop
```

Other method:

```
public class Bols{ 
private boolean corDes; 
private boolean corPiece; 
add getters and create a constructor
public Bols(boolean corDes, boolean corPiece){ 
this.corDes = corDes; this.corPiece = corPiece;
} 
}
```

Then create

```
Bols object = new Bols(boolean correctDest, boolean correctPiece);
return Bols;
```

use getters to retrieve your booleans;

Answer (score 1):

When I want to return several values, e.g. a complex result, i would create a new class for it. This makes code easier to read.

Besides that, your code is quite a mess, because:

- *correctPiece* is not changed at all in the loop
- the resetting of *correctDest* in the if() block is redundant and the resetting of *correctPiece* is not necessary or maybe even buggy, depending on the logic outside the while()
- *found* is not needed at all
- the return statement should be outside of the loop; in your example the return statement will be executed with the first loop and the user won't be given a second chance to click on a destination

My proposal for the code is like this

```
////
public class UserInputValidationResult {
    boolean correctPiece;
    boolean correctDest;

    public UserInputValidationResult(boolean correctPiece, boolean correctDest) {
        this.correctPiece = correctPiece;
        this.correctDest  = correctDest;
    }

    public boolean getCorrectPiece() {
        return correctPiece;
    }

    public boolean getCorrectDest() {
        return correctDest;
    }
}
/////

// I suppose this happens somewhere before the while()
correctPiece = true;
correctDest  = false;

while(correctPiece && !correctDest) {

    System.out.println("Click on a destination");

    toXCo = s.getToXInt();
    toYCo = s.getToYInt();

    Move found = null;

    for( Move m : moves){
        //checks if move can be done
        if (m.ToX() == toXCo && m.ToY() == toYCo){
            //if move is allowed- exit loop
            found = m; 
            correctDest = true;
        }
    }

    if (found == null) {
        //if move can't be, ask for new co-ordinates
        System.out.println("This move is not legal \n");
    }
}

return new UserInputValidationResult(correctPiece, correctDest);
```

but I am quite uncertain if it is the final version of the code which you are looking for.

If you are new to programming and learning about loops, functions, datatypes and return statements, try with something simpler in the beginning. Try to split complex statements into shorter ones. For example, move the inner loop into a function:

```
private boolean isCorrectDest(toXCo, toYCo) {
    boolean result = false;

    Move found = null;
    for( Move m : moves){
        //checks if move can be done
        if (m.ToX() == toXCo && m.ToY() == toYCo){
            //if move is allowed- exit loop
            found = m; 
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result; // and why did we define found?
}

while(correctPiece && !correctDest) {

    System.out.println("Click on a destination");
    toXCo = s.getToXInt();
    toYCo = s.getToYInt();

    correctDest = isCorrectDest(toXCo, toYCo);
    if (!correctDest) {
        //if move can't be, ask for new co-ordinates
        System.out.println("This move is not legal \n");
    }
}
```